# Passing arguments from my bash script into a c program

Tags: c, bash, shell, arguments

Im trying to use one of the inputs from my bash script into my c program and i just dont know how to do so.
What command should i add for the argument to be passed on to my c program?
Thanx
My script is -
[bash script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJxqH.png)

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Post your code as properly formatted text into the question. Before doing so read this: [ask]

Comment: Hint: `argc` and `argv` in `main()`. That's *exactly* what they're for. `prog.exe blah blah`.

Comment: Checkout : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean

Comment: A very complete answer about this problem can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean

Comment: yeah i know how to do that within my c prog i just dk what to write in my script: gcc -c -g -Wall calc_statistics.c 
gcc -o prog.exe calc_statistics.c "$1"

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to pass the argument to `prog.exe` and not to `gcc`, then

```
gcc -c -g -Wall calc_statistics.c gcc -o prog.exe && ./prog.exe "$1"
```

That is, compile the program and if there are no error run it with the argument.

It's not very efficient to compile the program every time the script runs so you can move `gcc` out.

You can also check your script using [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).